# C++ application: discover other IPs on LAN

Tags: c++, linux, networking, udp, posix

I want to create a C++ application that can be used (in part) to communicate between users on a  local area network using UDP. Each instance of the application will have a thread dedicated to listening for other instances of the application and broadcasting its presence to other instances.

Is there a reliable way to perform this type of broadcast/listening on the LAN using pure C++ and POSIX system calls? I know there's no generally reliable way to find all IPs on a LAN, but I assume this is only because other devices are not willing to respond to pings.

Comment: You answered your own question - use a UDP broadcast. Create a UDP socket and `bind()` it to the local LAN adapter on a given port of your choosing, enable the socket's `SO_BROADCAST` option, and then send a message to the LAN's subnet broadcast IP via `sendto()`. Any app that is listening on the same port on the same LAN subnet can receive the message via `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` a reply back to the sender. Note this UDP broadcasting only works for IPv4. For IPv6, use multicast instead, where each machine joins the same multicast group, and can then broadcast messages to subscribers

Comment: Broadcasting is a rookie mistake. you should use multicast to communicate between device for the same group. That is the purpose of multicast.

Comment: How would you multicast? Also, can a port used for broadcasting also be used for general one-to-one communication between peers?

Answer (score 2):

Don't re-invent the wheel. There are two existing technologies, that, when combined, solve your problem in a standardized, well-designed, proven manner:

- [RFC6762 *mDNS* (Multicast DNS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762.txt) is a protocol that works almost exactly like DNS, except it works using IP multicast. Instead of sending your DNS request to a unicast address, you send your DNS request to a multicast group, and any member of that group can answer your request (so you may get multiple answers).
- [RFC6763 *DNS-SD* (DNS-based Service Discovery)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6763.txt) is a way to encode Services as DNS entries, which allows you then to retrieve Services from DNS using specially encoded hostnames. (For example, looking up the hostname `_ipp._tcp.example.com` would return a list of all printers that support the Internet Printing Protocol over TCP within the domain example.com)

So, we have one protocol that allows us to ask DNS about Services, and we have one protocol that allows us to ask a group of hosts to answer DNS queries … when we put the two together, we get a way of asking hosts for services! The combination of those two protocols is sometimes called Zeroconf networking, and is already implemented in macOS, iOS, tvOS, and watchOS (where it is called Bonjour), Android, most Unices (via Avahi, a portable implementation of those two protocols), and many home devices such as TVs. E.g. Spotify Connect, ChromeCast, Philips Hue and many others are also based on it. It's how iTunes devices find each other on the local network, for example.

Unfortunately, support in Windows is still limited, at the moment it seems to only exist for Windows 10 apps implemented in ECMAScript. (However, nothing stops you from shipping your own implementation with your app, and AFAIK, both Avahi and Apple's mDNSResponder work on Windows.)

So, what you would basically do is to send an mDNS query to the mDNS multicast group and ask for `_myprotocol._udp.local.` Then, assuming that your application registers itself with the OS's mDNS service (i.e. Bonjour on macOS, Avahi on Unices, …), you would get back a list of all hosts on the local network that support your protocol.